# How to plot bar charts with 'n' number of columns and group by another column?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am learning r currently and I have an r data-frame containing data I have scraped from a football website.
There are 58 columns(Variables,attributes) for each row. Out of these variables, I wish to plot 3 in a single bar chart.I have 3 important variables 'Name', 'Goals.with.right.foot', 'Goals.with.left.foot'.
What I want to build is a bar chart with each 'Name' appearing on the x-axis and 2 independent bars representing the other 2 variables. 
Sample row entry:
{......., RONALDO, 10(left), 5(right),............}

I have tried playing around a lot with ggplot2 geom_bar with no success.
I have also searched for similar questions however I cannot understand the answers. Is anyone able to explain simply how do I solve this problem?

#### my data frame is called 'Forwards' who are the strikers in a game of football. They have attributes Name, Goals.with.left.foot and Goals.with.right.foot.

```
barplot(counts, main="Goals",
        xlab="Goals", col=c("darkblue","red"),
        legend = rownames(counts))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try it this way:

I simulated a frame as a stand in for yours, just replace it with a frame containing the columns you're interested in:

```r
df <- data.frame(names = letters[1:5], r.foot = runif(5,1,10), l.foot = runif(5,1,10))

# transform your df to long format
library(reshape2)
plotDf <- melt(df, variable.name = 'footing', value.name = 'goals')

# plot it
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(plotDf, aes(x = names, y = goals, group = footing, fill = footing)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) #does the same as geom_bar, but uses stat_identity instead of stat_count
```

Results in this plot:
[your plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxiYK.png)

This works, because ggplot expects one variable containing the values needed for the y-axis and one or more variable containing the grouping factor(s).
with the `melt`-function, your `data.frame` is merged into the so called 'long format' which is exactly the needed orientation of data.

Comment: This works and I had seen solutions similar to this one but I just can't understand what r means by 'long' format. How does long format compare to the concept of normalization in databases ? If I want to represent this data, I would always assign a column to goals with r foot and goals with l foot instead of having a goals column and a footing column. Since a single row should represent a single entity(player) i don't see the advantage of splitting 1 row into 2 by having columns like goals and footing instead of 2 columns like l foot goals and r foot goals. What do you think ?

Comment: The author of ggplot2 wrote a [paper](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.html) about the ideas behind 'tidy' data-structures, i.e. data in long format. Maybe this can help you in understanding the logic. Although I do see your argument in terms of space etc., the practical advantages outweigh them, as far as I am concerned.